# SwiftUI - making view within VStack fill available space in ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, vstack

I have a view where the basic structure is as follows (this is just a bare representation of my actual view obviously):

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Logo and postcode search
                VStack {
                    Text("Logo")
                        .background(Color.red)
                    
                    Text("Title")
                        .background(Color.blue)
                }
                
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .padding()
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
             
                        Text("Selector")
                            .background(Color.yellow)
                        
                        Text("Browse")
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .background(Color.green)
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is have the "Browse" section fill all the available space from its starting position to the bottom of the screen. However, here is how it currently looks:

[image]

If I set a concrete height to the 'browse' text (e.g. `frame(height: 400)`) it increases the height accordingly. However, given that the view is within the scroll view which we can see in turn is the full height of the screen, I thought that setting the `maxHeight` property to `.infinity` would have the desired effect, but clearly not. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure I understand 100% but as is your code already achieves that. If you provide a text that is very long the "browse" text view will fill the space as intended.

Comment: So for example, switch out the Text("") with e.g. `Rectangle()` and apply the same frame modifier. I want that entire view to fill the entire space available, whereas currently, it does not.

Answer (score 0):

We need to calculate that manually, because ScrollView requires finite intrinsic content size.

Here is a possible approach. Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

```
GeometryReader { gp in
    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text("Selector")
                .background(Color.yellow)

            Text("Browse")
                .frame(minHeight: height, alignment: .top)
                .background(GeometryReader {
                    Color.clear.preference(key: ViewOffsetKey.self,
                        value: $0.frame(in: .named("parent")).origin.y)
                })
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
    .coordinateSpace(name: "parent")
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewOffsetKey.self) {
        height = gp.size.height - $0
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
```

[Complete code in project](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestSomeViewFillInScrollView.swift)